# moved ubuntu folder from C: to D: drive how to correct UUID entries

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, wubi, uuid

I had a previous Ubuntu 11.10 installation which was done using Wubi in
D: drive of my computer. The corresponding grub.cfg entries are:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1546414/

Now I wanted to use Ubuntu 12.04 so I deleted the previous
installation from the D: drive
and then installed Ubuntu 12.04. I accidentally installed it to the C: drive instead of installing it in
the D: drive, and the grub entries here are
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1546422/

I didn't have enough space in the C: drive so I moved the ubuntu folder from
C: drive to D:, but surprisingly it could not boot. 
Realizing that grub.cfg needed to be updated I opened the old grub.cfg
(this 11.10 was installed  in D: drive)

and checked the UUIDs grub.cfg which are (for previous 11.10 install in D: drive)

```
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8E9E86339E86143D

linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic root=UUID=8E9E86339E86143D
loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro
```

in the new 12.04 grub.cfg (which was accidentally installed in C: drive )

has following grub.cfg  (for 12.04 in C: drive)

```
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root E4ACAFF5ACAFC082
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic root=UUID=E4ACAFF5ACAFC082
loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro
```

I have since moved the entire Folder C:\ubuntu to D: drive so it is
now D:\ubuntu

what I notice is the old UUID entries (from 11.10 ) are not the same
as the  UUID entries in 12.04 is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down Shift key after selecting Ubuntu. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit grub entries manually if you know how. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.

If you don't know how to edit the grub entries, press <kbd>C</kbd> to get to a grub prompt. Then enter the following:

```
search -s -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
probe --set=diskuuid -u $root
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

After booting, enter `sudo update-grub` to fix grub.cfg.

Comment: yes I know editing of grub etc (I have done all that in past) and what about the Windows UUID will update-grub fix that