# Moving a Wubi install to a different Windows 'drive'

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2, wubi, uuid

I was wanting to move my wubi install from drive `E:` to `C:` as to have a working backup location that is not on the drive which I will be migrating to a regular install. (I want to make the `E:` drive a Linux partition.)

I read 
[moved ubuntu folder from C: to D: drive how to correct UUID entries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244758/moved-ubuntu-folder-from-c-to-d-drive-how-to-correct-uuid-entries?lq=1)
and [How to convert Wubi install into regular install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install) for migration at another time.

And, I tried to figure out were my grub.cfg file is. The only thing I found was an empty grub directory, and did the following. By going into Windows renaming the Ubuntu folder to Ubuntu-test and tried to reboot into Ubuntu. What I got was an error message with a `File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr` with the `status: 0xc000000f`. I rebooted again and went back to Windows and renamed the folder back to Ubuntu. Back to the same Ubuntu with all of my settings and configurations.

I also copied all the files and folders in `E:\ubuntu` to `C:\ubuntu` before this renaming and un-renaming above. So the question is: What do need to do in order to move this to `C:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On XP it runs `C:\wubildr.mbr`. On Windows Vista/7/8 it runs `\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr` on the drive you installed on. So moving the Ubuntu folder to a different partition will give you a `wubildr.mbr is missing or corrupt` message like you saw.

You can just edit the [BCD store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Configuration_Data#Boot_Configuration_Data) directly by going to a command prompt (`CMD.exe`, making sure you select `Run as administrator`) and then changing the Ubuntu entry:

```
bcdedit /set {uuid} device partition=C:
```

(You have to figure out what the `uuid` is, by first running `bcdedit` and copying the one that shows for your Wubi entry. e.g.

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {1476af5e-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
displayorder            {current}
                        {1476af63-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 10

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {1476af60-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {1476af5e-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
nx                      OptIn

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {1476af63-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
description             Ubuntu

C:\windows\system32>bcdedit /set {1476af63-e5bc-11de-b180-0024543ae029} device partition=C:
```

Any BCD changes have to made while running Windows or booting to a Windows repair prompt.

Comment: That all looks like it needs to be done in Windows. Can it be done in Ubuntu also?

Comment: Another question, what is a BCD?

Comment: Answer updated to address comments.

Comment: Had a small problem, which took me a few days to figure out. I was starting to do the second thing stated above, the migrate, which meant that I needed to make the E: drive a linux drive. After using Gparted, I found out that I did not have my Grub correct and had to use Windows to find https://answers.launchpad.net/wubi/+question/186778 which fix the problem. I think the line "sudo update-grub" is what I did not do or needed to do in the first place before I even started on the migrate. Is this correct?